# How to create squiggly line along path?

Tags: modeling

I want to create a squiggly line along a path compared to the Object to the right, but I haven't been able to figure out how to recreate it.

Object I want to adjust to the left, Object to the right the reference.

[image: Object I want to adjust to the left, Object to the right the reference.]

Is it even possible using this method? And if so how can I recreate the effect on the right without doing it manually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create this wave shape from a mesh circle:

[image]

Create the heart from a curve circle:

[image]

Give your wave an *Array* modifier (to repeat it) and a *Curve* modifier (to give it the heart shape):

[image]

Extrude down the shape, give it thickness with a *Solidify* modifier, smooth the shape with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while figuring out the offset and such, how I did it for people interested:

Took a circle mesh, Copied (Shift+D) half the circle, moved (G) bottom half Left side to align with vertex on the top right side for a nice wave. Used Scale (S) on axis to create a smaller wave.

Then I copied the heart outline (Alt+LMB), Seperate (P) by selection. Went into object mode, Converted heart shape into Curve, and continued the steps from Moonboots.

The Result:[image]