# How to tell a vertex to have its normal perpendicular to the tangent of its edge?

Tags: vertices, transforms, edges, normals

I have this mesh containing only edges and vertices with checker-selected vertices and wanted to scale them out in a way that is perpendicular to the tangent line intersecting each vertex. I learned that the vertex Normal is by Blender definition pointing away from the Origin. How do I accomplish this or is there a way to set the vertex Normals to be perpendicular to the tangent? I tried all the *Transform Pivot Point* options to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Have we all been checking out @moonboots ' answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/284030/35559) ? I had a play, and came to the conclusion his method was better :)

Comment: haha yes! i wanted to scale inwards and then do a subdivision surface. i think that would have worked! unfortunately i ran into this normals problem and thought hmm this is interesting to know, looks like GN or custom normal splits is the way i guess +1 btw thanks for the answer il have to check!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. The normal to a faceless mesh-vertex is its normalized position, in object-space. A curve has more information in its control-points.. so you could use the normal of the mesh-converted-to-curve, and convert back again, via Geometry Nodes. GN can make the selection for you, too:

[image]

Comment: I'll add to this: you can't modify normal, but you can modify custom normal ("Custom Split Normals Data"). Though custom split normals are face corners, right? So not in this case. Also how about just temporarily adding a face?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Ahh !  That sounds like an answer in its own right !  How would you set the custom normals appropriately, and then use them?

Comment: I wouldn't, I was about to also suggest GN :D https://i.imgur.com/Q3QJN6K.gif However it looks like custom split normals have some potential here: https://i.imgur.com/Ddl06gV.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady agreed! But I don't know how to get at them.